# ASP.NET MVC 3 and the Entity Framework with MySQL and LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have downloaded ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am now ready to use a MySQL database as my source of data.

I have understood that the Entity Framework will allow me to abstract the actual sql-business out, and I can wrap my linq queries in a repository pattern.
I have tried to follow http://pattersonc.com/blog/2009/04/01/using-mysql-with-entity-framework-and-aspnet-mvc-%E2%80%93-part-i/ but when I get to the place reading

```
var result = from p in mySqlEntities.ProductSet select p;
```

I realize that I don't have such a ProductSet.

So, is this the right way of doing things, or is there some easier or more preferable way?

Comment: Are you using EF 4? What entities do you have in your model?

Answer (score 0):

Every entity in the Domain Model will have a set, you might not have a 'product' set but if you had a product table, it definitely would.

Comment: I think I was to reexamine the whole EF idea. Thanks for answers.